# ObservableCollection of type (string, bool) is not being bond to the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I need to create a list of check boxes and bind those check box values. So here is my code.

MV_Main._selectedStepRelaysForUI_CollectionChanged() is called 4 times since items are added in the MV_Main constructor.

I have 4 check boxes that appear in the window. They are all false, and the Labels are blank. Clicking them does not result in _selectedStepRelaysForUI_CollectionChanged() being called.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong and then what I need to do to to make binding work correctly?

here is my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Hipot_Sequence_Editor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hipot_Sequence_Editor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="677.538" Width="896.456">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MV_Main></local:MV_Main>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStepRelaysForUI}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel x:Name="RelayStatus">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="100" Height="Auto">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Item1}"/>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Item2}"></CheckBox>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my Model View Called MV_Main

```
class MV_Main : ObservableObject
{

    private ObservableCollection<(string,bool)> _selectedStepRelaysForUI = new ObservableCollection<(string, bool)>();


    public MV_Main()
    {
        _selectedStepRelaysForUI.CollectionChanged += _selectedStepRelaysForUI_CollectionChanged;


        //** Test Data
        _selectedStepRelaysForUI.Add(("1",false));
        _selectedStepRelaysForUI.Add(("2", true));
        _selectedStepRelaysForUI.Add(("3", false));
        _selectedStepRelaysForUI.Add(("4", true));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<(string,bool)> SelectedStepRelaysForUI
    {
        get { return _selectedStepRelaysForUI; }
        set
        {
            _selectedStepRelaysForUI = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(SelectedStepRelaysForUI));
        }
    }

    private void _selectedStepRelaysForUI_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        Console.WriteLine("_selectedStepRelaysForUI_CollectionChanged");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `(string,bool)` you are creating a `Tuple<string,bool>`. Tuple are value types, which means you are not able to bind two way because changing one item needs to replace the whole item in the collection. You need to implement a class which contains your properties and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` like

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _StringItem;
    public string StringItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _StringItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _StringItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StringItem));
        }
    }

    private bool _BoolItem;
    public bool BoolItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _BoolItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _BoolItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BoolItem));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Binding inside your `ItemsControl` would now look like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding StringItem}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolItem}"></CheckBox>
```

During fill up, you can attach an event handler to get internal changes of the items like

```
public MV_Main()
{
    ...
    MyClass cl = new MyClass() { StringItem = "1", BoolItem = false };
    cl.PropertyChanged += Cl_PropertyChanged;
    SelectedStepRelaysForUI.Add(cl);
}

private void Cl_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Changed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CollectionChanged event is thrown when an item is added/removed or replaced in the collection, not when an item in the collection has been changed.

Secondly the ValueTuple type you are using in your collection (i.e. (string, bool)) is implemented with fields Item1 and Item2 not properties, so those fields are not bindable at all.

You will need to write a class to hold your data and implement INotifyPropertyChanged and listen for their changes in order to do what you want.